# JS HTMLCanvas help required

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a game (at beginning stages). I am trying to create balls that bounce around a canvas, I have created balls, randomized them and have animated them. 
But when trying to add a boundary I can only seem to get the balls to act as one object rather than separate ones. If NumShapes is changed to 1 it works perfectly.

```
if( shapes[i].x<0 || shapes[i].x>width) dx=-dx; 
if( shapes[i].y<0 || shapes[i].y>height) dy=-dy;
```

For movement:

```
   shapes[i].x+=dx;
   shapes[i].y+=dy;
```

---

See this:

```js
var ctx;
    var numShapes;
    var shapes;
    var dx = 5; // speed on the X axis
    var dy = 5; // speed on the Y axis
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;

    function init() // draws on the Canvas in the HTML
      // calling functions here would not run them in the setInterval
      {
        numShapes = 10;
        shapes = [];
        drawScreen();
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        setInterval(draw, 10); // Runs the Draw function with nestled functions
        makeShapes();
      }

    function draw() {
      clear();
      drawShapes();

    }

    function clear() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); // clears the canvas by WIDTH and HEIGHT variables
    }

    function makeShapes() {
      var i;
      var tempRad;
      var tempR;
      var tempG;
      var tempB;
      var tempX;
      var tempY;
      var tempColor;
      for (i = 0; i < numShapes; i++) { // runs while i is less than numShapes
        tempRad = 10 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 25); // random radius number
        tempX = Math.random() * (width - tempRad); // random X value 
        tempY = Math.random() * (height - tempRad); // random Y value
        tempR = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255); // random red value
        tempG = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255); // random green value
        tempB = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255); // random blue value
        tempColor = "rgb(" + tempR + "," + tempG + "," + tempB + ")"; // creates a random colour
        tempShape = {
          x: tempX,
          y: tempY,
          rad: tempRad,
          color: tempColor
        }; // creates a random shape based on X, Y and R
        shapes.push(tempShape); // pushes the shape into the array
      }
    }

    function drawShapes() {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < numShapes; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = shapes[i].color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(shapes[i].x, shapes[i].y, shapes[i].rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        shapes[i].x += dx; // increases the X value of Shape
        shapes[i].y += dy; // increases the Y value of Shape

        // Boundary, but applies to all shapes as one shape
        if (shapes[i].x < 0 || shapes[i].x > width) dx = -dx;
        if (shapes[i].y < 0 || shapes[i].y > height) dy = -dy;
      }
    }

    function drawScreen() {
      //bg
      ctx.fillStyle = '#EEEEEE';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
      //Box
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
      ctx.strokeRect(1, 1, width - 2, height - 2);


    }
```

```css
canvas {
     border: 1px solid #333;
   }
```

```html
<body onLoad="init();">

  <div class="container container-main">
    <div class="container-canvas">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
        This is my fallback content.
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your movement should also be per shape, rather than universal, so declare them as arrays, and push the speeds when you create your shape. Or integrate the movement of the shape inside the shape object, instead of outside it

Comment: Edited your fiddle for you to fix problem : https://jsfiddle.net/a9b3rm5u/3/ as was suggested, add a local dx and dy per shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dx` and `dy` are globals, they should be unique for each ball object that you are simulating. Either clear them to 0 in your rendering loop (`draw`) or actually implement a `ball` object/class to hold variables unique to that object.

When you do your collision detection you change `dx` and `dy` which then persists to the next ball object as they are global.

Your fiddle, edited to add local dx and dy per shape: https://jsfiddle.net/a9b3rm5u/3/

```
tempDx = Math.random()*5; // random DX value 
tempDy = Math.random()*5; // random DY value

shapes[i].x+=shapes[i].dx;// increases the X value of Shape
shapes[i].y+=shapes[i].dy;// increases the Y value of Shape

if( shapes[i].x<0 || shapes[i].x>width) shapes[i].dx= - shapes[i].dx; 
if( shapes[i].y<0 || shapes[i].y>height) shapes[i].dy= -shapes[i].dy;
```

Comment: Edited your answer with the code I added to the fiddle, looks solid now.

Comment: Obviously my knowledge is pretty limited, how would i go about having a class/object then pushing the shapes to the canvas? my idea is to have the shapes clickable would that method be better for that?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @AndrueAnderson, much better with an example! Noobcoder start with something like [this OOP example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_objects) and work up from there.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and the help. Cheers guys